C compilation error for code that is otherwise normal
I have a minGW GCC compiler on my system. I am writing the code in C. Something that's otherwise normal is not getting properly compiled due to some reason.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}

void sayHi(){
    printf("Hello bro");
}

The output in cmd is: 6:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sayHi' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
Then it says 10:6: warning: conflicting types for 'sayHi' void sayHi(){. 
Furthermore, :6:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'sayHi' was here sayHi();


I tried the same on online compiler, but still this doesn't work and gives the same error. However, in freecodecamp tutorial, the same code was written, but it got executed perfectly. How is that possible?

You may want to read about some language basics in a textbook of your choice. tl;dr - whenever a compiler encounters a name for the first time, it must be able to conclude a name of what kind of entity it encountered. To that end, every function must be at least declared before getting called, telling the compiler "sayHi is a name of a function accepting no arguments and returning nothing", like so: void sayHi(); (before main()).

Oh thanks a lot! I know that in C the compiler would read one line and then go to the next. So if I place void sayHi() before int main() then the code works fine. I was just baffled why that was not the case with the dude on freecodecamp tutorial vid :/ I mean he placed void sayHi() after int main() but it worked for him!?

@Student probably the  freecodecamp tutorial video you mention is crap, like many tutorials. But be aware that these are warnings not errors, therefore is may very well work.

Don't use random C tutorials you find on the interwebs, 99.99% of them are worse than worthless.

Thank you everyone for your feebacks and providing me the right direction :)

When the compiler sees sayHi(); it has not yet "seen" void sayHi(), and therefore it considers sayHi() implicitly to be declared as int sayHi().
Then it "sees" void sayHi(), but as sayHi() is now (implicitly) declared as int sayHi(), the return type is now conflicted, hence the warning.
As a rule of thumb you should consider warnings containing the word "implicit" as errors.
You want this:
void sayHi();  // declare explicitly before using it

int main() {
    
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}

void sayHi(){
    printf("Hello bro");
}

or this:
void sayHi() {            // put the whole function before using it
    printf("Hello bro");  // which declares it as void
}

int main() {    
    sayHi();
    return 0;
}

Even better:
void sayHi() should be rather be void sayHi(void), which declares that the sayHi function takes no parameters at all.

The compiler needs to know about the sayHi() function before it is used. There are two options:

Move the sayHi() function definition above the main function.

Declare the sayHi() function before the main function like:
void sayHi();


